A question from STEMS (by CMI) involving polynomials and a bit of algebra
The Question is:

The roots in $\mathbb{C}$ of $x^9 - 2x^8 + 3x^7 + 5x^5 - 2x^2 + 3x - 6$ are permuted and written on a board. The following operation is repeated till there is a single number on the board s: two adjacent numbers x and y are chosen and replaced with $\frac{xy}{x+y}$
. Find the sum of all distinct s for all
such permutations of the roots.

I thought something like this:
Let the roots be $x_1, x_2,x_3, ... , x_9$
If you add the variables in any order, the variables at the end reached to 
$\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_9}{\sum_{cyc}^{} x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8}$
Using vietas formula $\sum_{}^{}x_1 = 2$ and $\sum_{}^{} x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8 = 3$ and getting the answer as $\frac{2}{3}$ but it is a integer type answer, so obviously its wrong.
Please correct me.

This question is from STEMS 2024 Category A Question number 4

Hint: Check the numerator again

@SohamSaha oh thanks, I forgot that in the numerator it has to be in multiplication (my calculation mistake), and then the answer would be 6/3 = 2.

You can add an answer yourself, and after a few days, mark it as accepted.

@SohamSaha Surely, I will

apparently https://cdn.tessellate.cmi.ac.in/stems/PastPapers/STEMS2024-Maths-CategoryA.pdf   which happened late 2023

The equation is $x^9 - 2x^8 + 3x^7 + 0x^6 + 5x^5 + 0x^4 + 0x^3 - 2x^2 + 3x  - 6$
Let the 9 roots be $x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_9$
The Magic is that if we simplify it in any order we get the same final result
$\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2}, x_3, x_4, ... , x_9$
$\frac{\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2} x_3}{\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1+x_2}+x_3}, x_3, x_4, ... , x_9$
$\frac{x_1x_2x_3}{x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1}, x_4, ... , x_9$
$\frac{x_1x_2x_3x_4...x_9}{\sum_{cyc}{}x_1x_2x_3x_4...x_8}$
By vietas relation, 
$x_1x_2x_3x_4...x_9 = 6$ and $\sum_{cyc}{}x_1x_2x_3x_4...x_8 = 3$
$\frac{6}{3} = 2$
Thus the final answers is 2
